# Group the lines of an array based on a number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grouping

I have an array with 100 lines and 5 columns. I would like to group them in separate arrays, based
on a number given in the 5th column. The 5th column contains integer numbers from 0 to N (0, 1, 2, ...N).

So for N=2, values in column 5th will be 0, 1, 2

thus I would like to create 3 arrays with the lines having 0, 1, 2 respectively.

here is the code in python for N=3:

```
df_array_with_clusters=... 

for i in range(len(df_array_with_clusters)):

 if df_array_with_clusters[i, -1]== 0:

  cluster_0[i,:] = df_array_with_clusters[i, :-1]

 elif df_array_with_clusters[i, -1]== 1:
  cluster_1[i,:] = df_array_with_clusters[i, :-1]

 else:
  cluster_2[i,:] = df_array_with_clusters[i, :-1]
```

thanks

Comment: The question you have asked is too abstract. Are you looking for just a human readable algorithm? How does the array have 100 lines and 5 columns? Is it an array of arrays or multi dimension array? If your are looking for help with code, what language?

Comment: sorry I am looking for a code for python. It's an numpy array.
I have done something when I have N=3, so the numbers in column 5th is 0,1,2.
I will post the code above! thnx

Comment: I have added tags to help potential experts find this question. I hope you find your answer. I'm not good with python.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Could you add an example input and what output you would expect from it?

Comment: @NikolasSpiliopoulos I've edited my answer to add a NumPy solution. Let me know if my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

### A solution using lists

Something like this should work for you:

```
def distribute_into_clusters(data, N):
    clusters=[[] for _ in range(N)]
    for row in data:
        cluster_id = row[-1]
        clusters[cluster_id].append(row[:-1])
    return clusters
```

What this returns is a list of clusters, each of which is a list of rows as np.array.

If you want each cluster to be an array instead, change the return statement to this:

```
    return [np.array(cluster) for cluster in clusters]
```

### A NumPy solution

Here's a second solution that distributes the data into clusters in NumPy. It might be more efficient.

```
def distribute_into_clusters(data, N):
    return [
        data[[row[-1] == cluster_id for row in data]][:,:-1]
        for cluster_id in range(N)
    ]
```

- `[row[-1] == cluster_id for row in data]` gives me a list of bools indicating which rows belong in `cluster_id`.
- `data[...]` slices data keeping only the rows where the bool is True
- `[:,:-1]` removes the cluster ID column

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer!
I will see it asap, and will let you know thanks again!

Comment: Hi again, the code runs fine
however I don't see any cluster as result in the console variables.

As I am beginner in python I have put the variables N and data(my own array), below the def but still it seems it doesn't do anything thanks!

Comment: Keep my function as shown (either version), and call it like this: `clusters = distribute_into_clusters(df_array_with_clusters, 3)`. Then `print(clusters)` will print all the clusters, and `print(clusters[0])` (change 0 to the index of the cluster you want to look at) will print one cluster.

Comment: The `def` syntax defines a function, but it does not get run until you call it.